"Nothing to update" when trying to deploy cloud function from current directory
I am running the command gcloud functions deploy functionname from the root of my functions directory as I've done a hundred times before but am getting the message Nothing to update. and it won't update.

It seems that setting --source=./ resolved this issue. However according to the help dialog, the current directory should be used by default if the source parameter is not specified. So I am considering this a bug
Found this existing issue that was just recently submitted: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/339596712
